# Blank page on remote server when using Axios baseURL option

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

My app is blank/empty when deployed on remote server but works fine locally (same static site build in both cases). It works on remote server only if I provide the full absolute path in my `Axios` calls, however if I use `Axios`'s `baseURL` option in `nuxt.config.js` then the app is blank on remote server.

What's going on?

.env:

```
BASE_URL=https://path.to.cdn
```

nuxt.config.js:

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
},
axios: {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
},
```

Comment: Nuxt does generate a `.gitignore` file when your project is created. So, even if you have your `.env` file in your project, this is probably (and SHOULD be) ignored by git. So, you need to pass env variables to where your website is hosted. Is it on Netlify or another platform ?

Comment: Sorry @kissu! A few things bother me. First I wanna configure it the idiomatic way without creating plugins/workarounds. Regarding `browserBaseURL` I'm not sure how to use that. Hell, I don't even understand what it's for.
I find `Nuxt` docs incredibly unhelpful, https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/ distinguishes `baseURL` from `browserBaseURL` in terms of "server side" vs "client side" requests, but what does that mean? Can't they use a real case scenario to explain in what kind of situation these apply? For semi-noobs like myself these docs are barely useful.
Anyway, I'm still in the dark..

Comment: Exporting the configuration allows more flexibility with the various axios options, handle the errors, interpolate more easily some variables and so on. It's not a workaround or a hacky way of doing. It is actually a recommended way of doing for some modules, like `@nuxtjs/apollo`. As for the variables, `baseURL` is the main one you need to focus on. `browserBaseURL` is here to (as stated in the docs), **only** if you want to have a different endpoint for the client calls. If you want to have the same endpoint for both server and client (probably your case IMO), you don't need to use it at all

Comment: If `browserBaseURL` is not specified, it defaults to `baseURL` as stated here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/#browserbaseurl So, if you do not specify it, it will have the same value as `baseURL`.

Comment: Is it more clean with my answer and comments ? :)

Comment: @kissu yes thanks to you I understand the problem way better now, and also I learnt something important about Axios configuration so thank you! I guess the correct answer to my particular problem is the one you provided on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803033/axios-baseurl-not-working-on-certain-hosts, would you agree?

Comment: BTW I've sent you a request on LinkedIn ("Fabrice"), I hope it's OK with you

Comment: Perfect so, glad that this helped! For the answer, each of them are pretty much fine and answer their own question. I just hoped to get mine accepted here because of the bounty lol. For LinkedIn, no issues my man! Just want to say that I'm not really into this platform (will still reply essentially here) but yeah, you'll be accepted! :)

Comment: Thanks! I did want to reward the time you spent on and the benefit I got from your interventions, but at the same time the root cause of my issue is - just as you suggested - an overriding baseURL on the server (which my team has just updated after I talked to them about it). So as genuinely heplful your answer is, it does not solve the problem raised in the question (so technically I can't accept it). Your comments do solve the problem though!

Answer (score 0):

On top of my comment above, I may add that this is a possible working and flexible configuration to have an axios working properly.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
},

...

plugins: [
  '~/plugins/nuxt-axios.js',
],
```

```js
// plugins/nuxt-axios.js
export default ({ $axios, $config: { baseUrl } }) => {
  $axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl
}
```

You may also try this alternative syntax as in the official docs: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#runtime-config

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi @kissu, I just implemented your answer with the `nuxt-axios.js` plugin. So endpoint path used to be `https://localhost:3000`, now it's the URL of the site - meaning where the app is deployed on the Amazon host. It's still not the API endpoint I specified in my `.env` file. Should we conclude that the `BASE_URL` used by the production build comes from an overriding `.env` file that I should ask to have replaced with my own?

Comment: The final URL depends of 2 things: where is the app built (`yarn build`) and what are the environment variables. Since it's in the `.gitignore`, it will not be available in git when pulled. So yeah, you need to see the actual values of the app (not obliged to be `.env`, can also be some input fields like on Netlify/Heroku). But yeah, you need to know and need to edit those to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the `@nuxtjs/axios` [docs](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#baseurl)

> Environment variable API_URL can be used to override baseURL.

So if you set `API_URL` and `API_URL_BROWSER` properly in your `.env` file then you don't need to explicitly set it in `nuxt.config.js`

After setting `API_URL` in your `.env` file if it does'nt work, try adding following code:

`require('dotenv').config()`
to your `nuxt.config.js`.

In order to enable usage of `dotenv`

Comment: `dotenv` is already backed into Nuxt (since v2.13), no need to set it up. More details here: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/