# Axios BaseURL not working on certain hosts

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

Below is how I configured Axios based on [the example given on Nuxt.js' website](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/modules-axios/):

.env:

```
BASE_URL=https://path.to.endpoint
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
},
```

On page load I make this call:

```
this.$axios.get(`/endpoint`)
```

Once I deploy my app as a static site it works both on my personal host and on GitHub pages. But on my employer's host, the path to endpoint specified in `.env` becomes `https://localhost:3000` so the API call fails.

Why is the most likely cause of this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by `employer's host` ? If he is a regular user, I cannot see how he can access any env variables. He also basically have access to the production website only no ? Or is he a developer too, who have access to the code repository ? If it's the case, he probably do have a `.env` config that is not matching yours or that is over-written somewhere.

Comment: I think the host is Amazon. I don't know if they have their own `.env` file, I've never been confronted with deployment before (somehow in all teams I've worked with, other people were taking care of that).
Let's assume there's a conflicting `.env` file, would the solution be simply to replace that file with my `.env` file?

Comment: Do you have a `.env` in your `.gitignore` ? Can you make a global search on your codebase and look for `localhost` (`ctrl` + `shift` + `f` should do the trick) ?

Comment: Yes I do, it's there by default I think

Comment: Can you make a global search on your codebase and look for localhost (ctrl + shift + f should do the trick) ?

Comment: Found it nowhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, from the comments, it looks like you configuration is totally fine from what you've provided and that the team on the other side does have an incorrect setup of the environment variables.

You need to ask where they do host your code and what are the actual values of their env variables. Actually, you will probably need to give it to them since they (usually) cannot guess it by themselves.

Human communication is the next step. ^^